# Django Admin: Restrict certain staff users to database records in their own group

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I want to build the admin site in a way such that, users in a certain group will be able to perform CRUD operations - to records related to their group only.

Is there a way this can be accomplished?

Answer (score -1):

You can easily use the Django Permissions and Group to create this. As the documentation states:

When django.contrib.auth is listed in your INSTALLED_APPS setting, it will ensure that four default permissions – add, change, delete, and view – are created for each Django model defined in one of your installed applications. [Read here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions)

You can then easily create Groups with certain permissions such as assigning only read permission to certain group and R/W to another in the Django Admin. If you need more finer record level access certain third party apps will help you such as [Django Guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian) or [Django role permissions](https://github.com/vintasoftware/django-role-permissions)